# ML.net Real-time object detection in C# forms

Tags: c#, object-detection, webcam, yolov5, ml.net

I would like to make an C# forms app which will detect traffic signs from my webcam using ML.NET library. The AI model I'm using it's YOLOV5 converted into onnx format.

I want my app to look something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gajSKEpn2r0
I know I'll propably  need this https://github.com/techwingslab/yolov5-net

To my knowladge Ml.net doesn't have native support for real-time object detection directly from a webcam. Most tutorials I've found show only image classification.
If that's the case how should I got about this ?